# Wordpress, use slug as variable not as page slug

Tags: wordpress

The problem:
I have a page that shows profiles: 'www.example.com/profile/1'

'1' being the ID of the profile, i retrieve the ID from the url and make a call to an external file to retrieve the profile information.

That all works fine.

But I now want to use the profile name instead of the ID: 'www.example.com/profile/nameOfProfile', Wordpress now searches for a page called 'nameOfProfile' which obviously does not exist.

My question now is: how can I make it so that the the url 'www.example.com/profile/nameOfProfile' loads the page 'www.example.com/profile' so I can manually retrieve the name from the url and make the call for the profile?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass the 'nameOfProfile' in the URL as the following given,

```
www.example.com/profile?name="nameOfProfile"
```

Then you need to rewrite the URL as the following given,

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/? /profile/?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```